# How to print very large object in wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, printing, flowdocument

I need to print very large and complicated object - virtualizet in two dimension matrix what have two tables at left and top side and at the middle represent the intersections of tables.
Each table can have more than 5000 records. So i made a control for all this things.
It's work pretty good. But customer wants to print it. When matrix too big for one page i should devide into peaces and print each part.

I can devide matrix by paper size and build flowdocument for each part. But it's smells with a lot of problems. Especially that's tables has custom count of the columns, so all of the columns cannot be placed at one document.

So, i hope that's exists any easiest way to implement this. (except print from excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "easy" way to do this is to create a bitmap the size of your document, draw every control in your document to this bitmap with `RenderTargetBitmap`, divide the bitmap into tiles the width and height of your page rectangle, and draw each tile to the printer.

Don't do that.

You will soon find that what looks good on screen does not look good on paper; fonts are pixelated, gradients are dithered, text gets cut off, blank areas in your document cause text to be printed at crazy locations. WPF controls are only available from the UI thread, and drawing them a lot can cause your UI to block.

Instead; take advantage of printer features. You have three tables? Print each table separately. Instead of trying to draw your UI, create a `DrawingVisual` for each cell or graphic. Lay out each cell on the page, testing to see if it goes outside the margin. If it does, add it to a horizontal (if it goes off the right margin) or vertical (if it goes off the bottom margin) slop list. After you have drawn the first page, draw all the visuals on the horizontal slop. Keep doing that until the horizontal slop is empty, then do it all again with the vertical slop. Then again for the next table. `DrawingVisual`s don't need the UI thread so you can do this in the background.

`DocumentPaginator` may have support for this; I haven't tried it. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't just render Visual objects because i haven't their. My control detect all free space and then draw himself. User should scroll to see other data. Table at left and top side is frozen. When user scrolling down then top table will stay where is she was and the same behavior have left table. At this moment i divide my control into repeatable templates. As result i have two-dimention array of the usercontrol's. For now i need to print all of this controls without print dialog... Or just send to print all of the parts.

Comment: For now my method is pretty fast. Maybe DrawingVisual will be better. I will look. But now i need to finish printing. Any one know how to send to print several visual elements?

Comment: What "visual elements"? `System.Windows.Media.Visual`s? That's an abstract class; post your code. Remember users cannot scroll controls printed to paper "to see other data".

Comment: Yes, that visuals.
I know that user cannot scroll printed controls. Previously i said that matrix can be very large. That's why my control draw only that part, what user can see. To see other matrix content user should "scroll" it. But it's not scrolling. Every time when user change the scrollbar value i change data for existing element. When user increase or decrease window size i add new or remove old UIElements... So, i need to render all matrix data(what i did using array of the usercontrols) and then print it. But DrawingVisual can be faster.